# IDEA: "Assign statement to new local variable"?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-completion

As a long time Eclipse user, I'm playing around a little bit with IntelliJ IDEA 10. I can't seem to find out how to perform an "Assign statement to new local variable" code completion.

**Feature explanation:**

I type something like

```
new BufferedOutputStream(out)
```

and then hit <kbd>Cmd (or Ctrl)</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and enter, and Eclipse changes the line into:

```
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
```

At the same time, I can type over "bufferedOutputStream" immediately to rename it (or select from the options "bufferedOutputStream", "outputStream" and "stream" from a dropdown).

I use this feature for absolutely every assignment, and it's an enormous time saver - this must be available in IDEA, too - but where is it hidden?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Refactor | Introduce Variable** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows). Note that you don't need to select the text if it's the only text in the current line. Then you can change the variable name in-line just like you've described and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete editing.

Another way is to use the [Postfix Completion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/):

Type `.var` (or just `.v` to select it from the list) and confirm it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Finally something that works in Android Studio similar to Eclipse.

Comment: Might be obvious, but for Apple users—`Cmd` + `Option` + `v` does the trick. Also, the resolve all is nice—it assigns the variable in the first expression and then replaces the other expressions in that scope with the new variable.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the Postfix Completion feature of IntelliJ. Typing ".v+ENTER" would normally choose the ".var" postfix completion and introduce the variable.

Comment: @LariHotari's comment should be part of the answer, it is much faster this way : https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/

Answer (score 11):

As CrazyCoder mentions you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Also instead of selecting the expression, clicking into somewhere in your expression and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to expand scope is very useful while using introduce refactorings. Extract refactorings are:

- Extract variable: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Extract field: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Extract method: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Extract parameter: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Extract constant: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Also, Idea is a polygot editor so you can use these extract refactorings for other file types like js or html also (not all refactorings work in all file types but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> works mostly).

There are more extract refactorings which do not have shortcuts which you can access from Refactor|Extract menu (both menu bar and context menu). To quick access all refactorings you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for a popup menu.

As a last word, I highly encourage you using "Tip of the Day" (Help|Tip of the Day). It is a fast way to learn many helpful features of Idea.

Answer (score 4):

It's not as nice as Eclipse, but you can try the following:

```
new BufferedOutputStream(out)
```

- Select the expression above, either with your mouse (or by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).
- Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to **Introduce a Variable** or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to **Introduce a Field**)

Comment: Selecting is not necessary in most cases, see my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, you will be offered with a list of options, and just select "Introduce local Variable".

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+2` at the end of the line and it will display this dialog at the bottom right of the screen

[image]

Select second option `Assign to local variable` and it will display this dialog with suggested variable names

[image]