# Assign to new local variable shortcut (ctrl-2 L) in android studio

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

I've just moved from Eclipse to android studio. One of my most used shortcut is ctrl-2 L, which will automatically assign a variable with a name and import the necessary class.

```
new View();
```

and press Ctrl-2 L, which results in:

```
View view = new View();
```

Is there a way to do it in android studio?

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816069/idea-assign-statement-to-new-local-variable

Comment: @plastiv - Thanks, i looked it up before posting the question but for some reason couldn't find it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You Can See Shortcut Key in Refactor -> Extract Menu

Mac Extract Variable Use Below Shortcut:

1- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for local variable

2- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for class/field variable

3- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for constant

I think you must use Control+Alt key for Windows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well this is pretty old but here is what I did just now.

I wrote

```
new View()
```

no column and space and just typed

```
new View().var
```

and pressed `CTRL+ [SPACE]` here's what appears:
[image]

and as I press `RETURN` on the suggestion bubble...

[image]

Voila!

Discovered this in a recent session on flutter using Intelli-J and since Android Studio is based on the same IDE so, it worked!